# Click on the button and show Alert

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The following code shows an alert box:

I want each box to be displayed by clicking on its own button
html

```
<button class="btn-alert btn-success" type="submit">delete</button>
<button class="btn-alert btn-success" type="submit">delete</button>
<button class="btn-alert btn-success" type="submit">delete</button>
<div class="alert-s col-4"></div>
<div class="alert-s col-4"></div>
<div class="alert-s col-4"></div>
```

```
<script>
      const targetDiv = document.getElementById("alert");
        const btn = document.getElementById("toggle");
         
        function clickfn() {
           for(let i = 0; i < targetDiv.length; i++) {
              if (targetDiv.style.display = "none") {
                 targetDiv.style.display = "block";
           } else {
                 targetDiv.style.display = "none";
           }
           }
          
        };
        
</script>
```

can anyone help me to do so?

Comment: Please mention what's the issue you are facing? Also getElementById returns an Element, not an array. So you for loop won't work. If you have multiple alert, use other APIs. Refer to MDN docs for the APIs you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to all your buttons, lets say `toggle`, then use `javascript` to call your `function` like:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('toggles');

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].onclick = function () {
        alert("Finaly!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the for loop as **getElementById** returns a single element.
If you want to show alert on both button click and don't want to write two separate codes give them a similar class name and query them that way using **document.querySelectorAll(*a dot class name in quotes*)**.

```
<button class="btn">Button one</button>
<button class="btn">Button two</button>

<script>
  const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].onclick = () => {
      alert(`button ${i + 1} was clicked`);
    };
  }
</script>
```